# How to come from $\frac{d}{dt} f(t) = \frac{2t}{1-t} f(t) + \frac{1}{(1-t)^2}$ to $f(t) =\frac{1-e^{-2t}}{2(1-t)^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

From an answer on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1913627/solving-the-recursive-equation-tn-1-frac2n-sum-i-1n-2ti), I got the differential equation

$$\frac{d}{dt} f(t) = \frac{2t}{1-t} f(t) + \frac{1}{(1-t)^2}$$

and I was even given the solution $$f(t) = \frac{1-e^{-2t}}{2(1-t)^2}.$$ It seems to be correct, however, I have trouble understanding *how* the solution was achieved. I tried building a power series $f(t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n t^n$ out of $f$ and finding the coefficients for it like in [this tutorial](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/SeriesSolutions.aspx), but I ended up in a huge ugly sum term

$$ a_n = \frac{(2t)^n}{n!(1-t)^n} a_0 + \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(2t)^{n-k}}{n!/k! (1-t)^{n-k}}. $$

Not fully shure if this is right. Somehow, the taylor series of the $e$-function sticks in there, but I don't think that this will lead to the solution above. So I am stuck here and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor

Comment: It is simply a linear differential equation

Answer (score 2):

$$y=f(t)$$
$$\frac {dy}{dt} -\frac {2ty}{(1-t)}=\frac{1}{(1-t)^2} $$
$$\text{I.F}=e^{2t}(t-1)^2$$
$$y\cdot e^{2t}(t-1)^2=e^{2t}dt $$
$$y\cdot e^{2t}(t-1)^2=\frac12e^{2t} + c$$
Given $f(0)=0$ $\implies c=-\frac12$
$$f(t)=\frac{1-e^{-2t}}{2(t-1)^2} $$

Explanation for fourth line :
$$\frac{dy}{dx} +Py =Q $$
where $P $ and $Q $ are function of $x $.

Multiply both sides by $e^{\int Pdx} $, we get
$$\frac{dy}{dx}e^{\int Pdx} +Pye^{\int Pdx} =Qe^{\int Pdx} $$
$$\implies \frac {d}{dx}{(ye^{\int Pdx})}=Qe^{\int Pdx}$$
$$\implies {d}{(ye^{\int Pdx})}=Qe^{\int Pdx}dx$$
Integrating both sides 
$$(ye^{\int Pdx})=Qe^{\int Pdx}+k$$
The factor $e^{\int Pdx}$ which makes it possible for the left hand side to be integrable is called an Integrating factor.

Comment: What does that period in $y.e^{2t}$ mean? Should it be $y \cdot e^{2t}$ ?

Comment: @MonkeySupersonic Fixed.

Comment: Even after hours I still don't understand what you are doing. Where does the Integrating Factor come from? What is the origin of line 4?

Comment: @MonkeySupersonic Do you know how to solve linear diffrential equation?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the comment of Hans Lundmark I am finally able to answer my own question. A good and understandable guide for solving linear differantial equations can be found [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Linear.aspx).

We firstable put the equation into some canonical form:

$$f^\prime(t) \ - \frac{2t}{1-t} f(t) = \frac{1}{(1-t)^2}. $$

Then we generate our integrating factor

$$ \mu(t) = e^{\int\,2t/(1-t)\ dt} = (1-t)^2 \cdot e^{2t}.$$

We multiply both sides of the equation with $\mu(t)$, do some simplification and get

$$\underbrace{f^\prime(t)}_{u^\prime}  \cdot \underbrace{(1-t)^2 \cdot e^{2t} }_v + \underbrace{(-2t) \cdot (1-t) \cdot e^{2t}}_{v^\prime} \cdot \underbrace{f(t)}_u = e^{2t}.$$

We make shure that $v^\prime$ is indeed a derivate of $v$ and then we can reverse the product rule which yields

$$\left(f(t)(1-t)^2 e^t\right)^\prime = e^{2t},$$

what we can integrate on both sides:

$$f(t)(1-t)^2 e^t + C = \frac{1}{2} e^{2t}.$$

Because we were given that $f(0) = 0$, we will insert it and $t=0$ as well and we get out $C=\frac{1}{2}$. We can insert $C$ again in the equation above and bring $f(t)$ alone on one side which gives

$$ f(t) = \frac{\frac{1}{2}e^{2t} - \frac{1}{2}}{(1-t)^2 e^{2t}}
= \frac{1-e^{-2t}}{2(1-t)^2}.
$$

And yes, this is basically, what Aakash Kumar did, but unfortunately he did not provide an explanation for any of his steps <del>and he twisted some literals in his answer (the denominator is $2(1-t)^2$, not $2(t-1)^2$)</del> , so I wanted to share my solution as well.

Comment: $$(a - b)^2=(b-a)^2$$ This is the explanation of twist I did .